# Solving inequalities for positive Integers

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following;

```
all = {a, b, c, d, e};
mean = Mean[all];
a1=Accumulate@Prepend[all, 0];
a2=Accumulate@Append[Table[mean, {i, Length[all]}], 0];
a3=a2-a1;
a4=Map[Reduce[# >= 0, all] &, a3]
```

Now I would like Mathematica to solve this with the restriction that all elements of `all` are positive Integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have to admit that I was hoping for a result that says that `a4` is always true, for all positive Integers, but as it appears this is not the case. However, I think we can leave my question with the edited heading as it is, in any case, somebody has a similar problem.

Answer (score 8):

[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) allows you to specify the domain of `Reals`, `Complexes`, or `Integers` as the third parameter. But, positivity is not directly specifiable at that point. Instead, it must be added to the `expr` being reduced as an added condition. A simple form of this condition would be

```
 And @@ Thread[all > 0]
```

which is equivalent to

> ```
> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0
> ```

Combining this with the `Integers` domain gives this form for `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[# >= 0 && And @@ Thread[all > 0], all, Integers] &
```

As a word of caution, this will result in a very, very large output as `Reduce` uses [`GeneratedParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeneratedParameters.html) for its unknown integer coefficients. For the second inequality, this results in 34 unknown coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

This may give you some ideas.

```
In[230]:= all = {a, b, c, d, e};
mean = Mean[all];
a1 = Accumulate@Prepend[all, 0];
a2 = Accumulate@Append[Table[mean, {i, Length[all]}], 0];
a3 = a2 - a1;
```

Your solution sets will be unbounded, and require many parameters to describe them. For purposes of illustration I opted instead to combine your inequalities and add another to make the set not too large.

```
solnb = 
 Reduce[Join[Thread[a3 >= 0], Thread[a3 <= 2], 
   Thread[all >= 1], {Element[all, Integers]}], all, 
  Backsubstitution -> True]

Out[237]= (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 1 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 1 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 3 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 3 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 4 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 3 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 3 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 4 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 4 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 4 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 3 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 3 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 1 && c == 4 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 3 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 2 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 3 && b == 3 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 3 && b == 3 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 4 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 4 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 3 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 4 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 4 && b == 1 && c == 2 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 4 && b == 1 && c == 3 && d == 1 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 4 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 1 && 
   e == 2) || (a == 4 && b == 2 && c == 1 && d == 2 && 
   e == 1) || (a == 4 && b == 2 && c == 2 && d == 1 && e == 1)
```

The way to specify your requirements can be taken from the Reduce invocation above.